# REACT - Divide background-color with containers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-color

I've been facing this issue over and over again and till this day I wasn't able to find the most optimized solution for it.

Let's say I have 2 DIVs, **A** and **B**. Both DIVs are inside a container and have a set of columns assigned to each. What would be the best way to fill a background color for both DIVs AND it would occupy the remaining left and right sides of the screen? With this I mean, the left background color would occupy full left DIV's width + remaining left width not used by the element. (same for right side)

Here's an image for better illustration: [imagine example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0jYq.png)

I know that by using linear-gradient we can split the background but in lower/higher viewports, it can become tricky.

I hope it won't be too confusing to understand and I apologize if it's too stupid.

Comment: Hi, since you are using react, why not pass in the color of the div as a prop to the parent container?

Comment: Could you expand on why linear gradient is not suitable as it seems like the obvious and simple answer.

Comment: @AHaworth linear-gradient would work fine if I would need to divide the 2 background colors 50/50. However, if it's not the case, in different viewports the wider background can overflow into the other element which should contain the other background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the best way to do this is by having the following:

```
    <div style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #8A66B9 50%, #ffff 50%);">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7" style="background-color:#8A66B9">
            A
          </div>
          <div class="col-5" style="background-color:#ffff">
            B
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thus, I have a parent DIV which has the background 50/50. Then, I set the background color for each of the backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you color the containers and make the div tranparent ?

```
<div class="orange-container">
  <div class="transparent-div">
    // Stuff here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blue-container">
  <div class="transparent-div">
    // Stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the whole of the container have say the orange color and then overwrite that with a pseudo element after component A. This would have background blue and be made taller and wider than is known to be needed so it covers the whole of the right hand side of the container starting from the right border of component A.

[image]

This snippet has had to invent how the components are placed but that is outside the scope of this question - it has just chosen arbitary left and top positions and sizes for demonstration purposes.

```css
<style>body,
.container,
.A,
.B,
.A::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: orange;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.A {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.B {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: calc(20% + 30%);
  /* just for demo */
  top: 10%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.A::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100vh;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  background: blue;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```